# Incompatible pointer types passing "UIImagePickerController *" to parameter of type "UIImage *"

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3

I am very new to Xcode, and I am trying to write an app that will allow the user to use the camera, take multiple pictures, and then allow the user to choose the pictures they would like to attach to an in-app email.
I am getting errors such as:

```
Incompatible pointer types passing "UIImagePickerController *" to parameter of type "UIImage *"
```

and

```
Instance method '_alloc' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

and

```
Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIImage *' to parameter of type 'NSString *'
```

and

```
Unused variable 'photoData'
```

Here is my code

```
// Camera Control

-(void) takePhotoClicked
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])

    {
        UIImagePickerController *theimagepicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        theimagepicker.delegate = self;

        theimagepicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        theimagepicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage] ;
        theimagepicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentModalViewController:theimagepicker animated:YES];
        [theimagepicker release];
        newMedia = YES;

    }
}

// Choose Photo Control

-(void) choosePhotoClicked
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *theimagepicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        theimagepicker.delegate = self;

        theimagepicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        theimagepicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
        theimagepicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentModalViewController:theimagepicker animated:YES];
        // Save image
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(theimagepicker, self, @selector(theimagepicker:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
        NSLog(@"Creating Mail Data!!!");
        NSData *photoData = [[UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"qwerty.png"], 1) alloc] init];

        [theimagepicker release];
        newMedia = NO;

    }
}



// Image Delegate Methods

-(void)theimagepickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage])
    {
        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        theimageView.image = image;
        if (newMedia)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector (image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);


        NSLog(@"Creating Mail Data!!!");
        NSData *photoData = [[UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"qwerty.png"], 1) alloc] init];


    }
    else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *) kUTTypeMovie])
    {


        // Code here to support video if enabled
    }
}

-(void)image:(UIImage *)image
finishedSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
 contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"Save failed"
                              message: @"Failed to save image"
                              delegate: nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }

}

// Email Control
#pragma mark - Open the mail interface
-(IBAction)email
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        //  NSString *custemail = txtCustomerEmail.text;

        //  NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:custemail];
        // [composer setToRecipients:toRecipients];

        [composer setSubject:@"Title Search results:"];

        [composer addAttachmentData:photoData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:[UIImage imageNamed:theimageView.image]];




        // Fill out the email body text
        NSString *emailBody =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Examiner Name :%@\nExaminer Address :%@\nExaminer City :%@\nExaminer State :%@\nExaminer Zip Code :%@\nExaminer Email Address :%@\nCustomer Name :%@\nCustomer Address :%@\nCustomer City :%@\nCustomer State :%@\nCustomer Zip Code :%@\nCustomer Email Address :%@\nSearch Through Date :%@\nTitle Held By :%@\nProperty Address :%@\nProperty City :%@\nProperty State :%@\nProperty Zip Code :%@\nProperty County : %@\nTitle Search Notes :%@\nMortgage 1 Lender :%@\nMortgage 1 Dated :%@\nMortgage 1 Recorded :%@\nMortgage 1 Amount :%@\nMortgage 1 Book Number :%@\nMortgage 1 Page Number :%@\nMortgage 1 Assignment :%@\nMortgage 1 Additional Info :%@\nMortgage 2 Lender :%@\nMortgage 2 Dated :%@\nMortgage 2 Recorded :%@\nMortgage 2 Amount :%@\nMortgage 2 Book Number :%@\nMortgage 2 Page Number :%@\nMortgage 2 Assignment :%@\nMortgage 2 Additional Info :%@\nMortgage 3 Lender :%@\nMortgage 3 Dated :%@\nMortgage 3 Recorded :%@\nMortgage 3 Amount :%@\nMortgage 3 Book Number :%@\nMortgage 3 Page Number :%@\nMortgage 3 Assignment :%@\nMortgage 3 Additional Info :%@\nLien/Judgement 1 Creditor :%@\nLien/Judgement 1 Type ;%@\nLien/Judgement 1 Dated :%@\nLien/Judgement 1 Recorded :%@\nLien/Judgement 1 Amount :%@\nLien/Judgement 1 Book Number :%@\nLien/Judgement 1 Page Number :%@\nLien/Judgement 1 Notes :%@\nLien/Judgement 2 Creditor :%@\nLien/Judgement 2 Type ;%@\nLien/Judgement 2 Dated :%@\nLien/Judgement 2 Recorded :%@\nLien/Judgement 2 Amount :%@\nLien/Judgement 2 Book Number :%@\nLien/Judgement 2 Page Number :%@\nLien/Judgement 2 Notes :%@\nLien/Judgement 3 Creditor :%@\nLien/Judgement 3 Type ;%@\nLien/Judgement 3 Dated :%@\nLien/Judgement 3 Recorded :%@\nLien/Judgement 3 Amount :%@\nLien/Judgement 3 Book Number :%@\nLien/Judgement 3 Page Number :%@\nLien/Judgement 3 Notes :%@\nProperty Tax ID :%@\nProperty Tax Amount :%@\nHow Often Are Taxes Paid :%@\nNext Payment Due Date :%@\nNext Payment Due Amount :%@\nExaminers' Notes Line 1:%@\nExaminers' Notes Line 2:%@\nExaminers' Notes Line 3:%@\nExaminers' Notes Line 4:%@\nExaminers' Notes Line 5:%@\nExaminers' Notes Line 6:%@\nExaminers' Notes Line 7:%@\nExaminers' Notes Line 8:%@\nExaminers' Notes Line 9:%@\nExaminers' Notes Line 10:%@\nLegal Description Line 1 :%@\nLegal Description Line 2 :%@\nLegal Description Line 3 :%@\nLegal Description Line 4 :%@\nLegal Description Line 5 :%@\nLegal Description Line 6 :%@\nLegal Description Line 7 :%@\nLegal Description Line 8 :%@\nLegal Description Line 9 :%@\nLegal Description Line 10 :%@\nLegal Description Line 11 :%@\nLegal Description Line 12 :%@\nLegal Description Line 13 :%@\nLegal Description Line 14 :%@\nLegal Description Line 15 :%@\nLegal Description Line 16 :%@\nLegal Description Line 17 :%@\nLegal Description Line 18 :%@\nLegal Description Line 19 :%@\nLegal Description Line 20 :%@\nLegal Description Line 21 :%@\nLegal Description Line 22 :%@\nLegal Description Line 23 :%@\nLegal Description Line 24 :%@\nLegal Description Line 25 :%@\nLegal Description Line 26 :%@\nLegal Description Line 27 :%@\nLegal Description Line 28 :%@\nLegal Description Line 29 :%@\nLegal Description Line 30 :%@", txtExaminerName.text, txtExaminerAddress.text, txtExaminerCity.text, txtExaminerState.text, txtExaminerZip.text, txtExaminerEmail.text, txtCustomerName.text, txtCustomerAddress.text, txtCustomerCity.text, txtCustomerState.text, txtCustomerZip.text, txtCustomerEmail.text, txtSearchThroughDate.text, txtTitleHeldBy.text, txtPropertyAddress.text, txtPropertyCity.text, txtPropertyState.text, txtPropertyZip.text, txtTitleSearchNotes.text, txtMtg1LenderName.text, txtMtg1Dated.text, txtMtg1Recorded.text, txtMtg1Amount.text, txtMtg1BookNumber.text, txtMtg1BookNumber.text, txtMtg1PageNumber.text, txtMtg1Assignment.text, txtMtg1AddlInfo.text, txtMtg2LenderName.text, txtMtg2Dated.text, txtMtg2Recorded.text, txtMtg2Amount.text, txtMtg2BookNumber.text, txtMtg2PageNumber.text, txtMtg2Assignment.text, txtMtg2AddlInfo.text, txtMtg3LenderName.text, txtMtg3Dated.text, txtMtg3Recorded.text, txtMtg3Amount.text, txtMtg3BookNumber.text, txtMtg3PageNumber.text, txtMtg3Assignment.text, txtMtg3AddlInfo.text, txtLien1Creditor.text, txtLien1Type.text, txtLien1Dated.text, txtLien1Recorded.text, txtLien1Amount.text, txtLien1BookNumber.text, txtLien1PageNumber.text, txtLien1Notes.text, txtLien2Creditor.text, txtLien2Type.text, txtLien2Dated.text, txtLien2Recorded.text, txtLien2Amount.text, txtLien2BookNumber.text, txtLien2PageNumber.text, txtLien2Notes.text, txtLien3Creditor.text, txtLien3Type.text, txtLien3Dated.text, txtLien3Recorded.text, txtLien3Amount.text, txtLien3BookNumber.text, txtLien3PageNumber.text, txtLien3Notes.text, txtPropertyTaxID.text, txtPropertyTaxAmount.text, txtHowTaxesArePaid.text, txtNextPaymentDueDate.text, txtNextPaymentAmount.text, txt1ExaminersNotes.text, txt2ExaminersNotes.text, txt3ExaminersNotes.text,txt4ExaminersNotes.text, txt5ExaminersNotes.text, txt6ExaminersNotes.text,txt7ExaminersNotes.text, txt8ExaminersNotes.text, txt9ExaminersNotes.text,txt10ExaminersNotes.text, txt1LegalDescription.text, txt2LegalDescription.text, txt3LegalDescription.text, txt4LegalDescription.text, txt5LegalDescription.text, txt6LegalDescription.text, txt7LegalDescription.text, txt8LegalDescription.text, txt9LegalDescription.text, txt10LegalDescription.text, txt11LegalDescription.text, txt12LegalDescription.text, txt13LegalDescription.text, txt14LegalDescription.text, txt15LegalDescription.text, txt16LegalDescription.text, txt17LegalDescription.text, txt18LegalDescription.text, txt19LegalDescription.text, txt20LegalDescription.text, txt21LegalDescription.text, txt22LegalDescription.text, txt23LegalDescription.text, txt24LegalDescription.text, txt25LegalDescription.text, txt26LegalDescription.text, txt27LegalDescription.text, txt28LegalDescription.text, txt29LegalDescription.text, txt30LegalDescription.text];

        //

        [composer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

        composer.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;

        [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];

        [composer release];
    }
    else
        [composer release];
}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"error"

                                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"error %@", [error description]]

                                                       delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];


        [alert show];
        [alert release];

        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }
    else {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay... and where exactly are you getting these errors?

Comment: At the line[composer addAttachmentData:photoData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:[UIImage imageNamed:theimageView.image]];   I get the Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIImage *' to parameter of type 'NSString *' twice

Comment: At the line NSData *photoData = [[UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"qwerty.png"], 1) alloc] init];  I get the Instance method '-alloc' not found (return type defaults to 'id') as well as Unused variable 'photoData' as well as Value stored to 'photoData' during its initialization is never read

Comment: At the line [theimagepicker release]; I get Potential leak of an object stored into 'photoData'

Comment: At the line       fieldArray = @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtExaminerName.text], I get Value stored to 'fieldArray' is never read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, in the method "choosePhotoClicked" delete these lines

```
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(theimagepicker, self, @selector(theimagepicker:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

    NSData *photoData = [[UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"qwerty.png"], 1) alloc] init];
```

Then remove this line from "didFinishPicking..."

```
    NSData *photoData = [[UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"qwerty.png"], 1) alloc] init];
```

Then in the action "email" replace this line:

```
    [composer addAttachmentData:photoData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:[UIImage imageNamed:theimageView.image]];
```

With these lines:

```
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theimageView.image, 1.0);
    [composer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"this is a string file name";
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Just a quick question... will this allow me now to choose multiple images and attach them to my email?

Comment: @user1539154 Glad to help, just be sure to mark my answer as correct if it helped you. It's a check mark icon next to my post. And as long as your create new NSData instances for each one multiple attachments should work. I'm not sure what the maximum size for an email is though.